# Simulate No Service on iOS device

Tags: ios, ipad, reachability, simulate

I am currently testing an iOS app on an iPad 4 with 3G running iOS 6. Part of the testing I need to do requires that I use the app when the iPad has different reachabilities (No Service, 3G, WiFi, Edge, Airplane).

Is there a way I can simulate the iPad to think it has no service other than me going underground and jumping on the tube. I have tried taking out the SIM card but it does not say No Service, it just says No SIM.

Thanks

Comment: make a small Faraday cage? :)

Answer (score 3):

Connect your device in Mac. In xcode's organiser allow the device for development if you have not done already. Once the device is ready you can see an option in your settings app named `Developer`.

That will have network link conditioner and all the settings.

Comment: As far as I am aware that option was removed in iOS 6 which is why I am now having difficulties trying to do this.

Comment: @user2099878 as far as I am aware that setting is there in the iOS 6 device that I am writing this comment on (just looked and it's there). Go look again.

Comment: This is not the same as "No Service"; and the network link conditioner has no setting for No Service. Our app behaves very differently in the two scenarios and thus I'm also looking for a simulator of "No Service".